# Connecting PowerBI Cloud to PostgreSQL

Tags: powerbi

I have a PowerBI instance and a Postgres database on Heroku.  In my search the PostgreSQL connectors for PowerBI all seem to be for desktop:
https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/integrations/postgresql/
https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-desktop-data-sources/

Has anyone found a connector for the cloud PowerBI solution?

Thanks!

Comment: have you been able to find a solution for this?

Answer (score 7):

The data source "connectors" for Desktop and the service "connectors" for the cloud are different things.

If you build a report in Power BI Desktop that connects to a PostgreSQL database data source, you can publish that report to PowerBI.com (the cloud) and configure a gateway to allow scheduled refreshes directly from the cloud (i.e. once configured, you can pull data from your PostgreSQL database via the gateway into the report in the cloud on a schedule). It sounds like this is what you were looking to do.

More information about the on-premises gateway, including the list that shows that PostgreSQL can be used via the gateway for a scheduled refresh: https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-gateway-onprem/#list-of-available-data-source-types

You cannot, however, start building a blank report in the cloud and connect to an on-premises PostgreSQL database. When you start out from the cloud, you can only connect to a more limited set of cloud-based data sources (Azure and SSAS). In general, you almost always want to start building your Power BI report in Power BI Desktop and then publish it to the cloud.

The service connectors in Power BI are something entirely different. They provide a quick way to connect to other cloud-based services you may subscribe to and bring in your personal data for reporting. E.g. if you use Salesforce, the Power BI connector will connect directly to Salesforce for you. This is different to connecting to your own database directly. It's not your database you're connecting to, but your data that belongs to a 3rd party service that's already in the cloud. More information here: https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-content-packs-services/

I hope this helps clarify things.